# Rails 3. How to add an API to a rails app

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to build a simple API that can be accessed by myself in other clients. I want to use Rails 3 to build it but I do not know how to do it. I know that Rails got this more or less build in but I do not know how to interact with it.

Is there any resources on the Internet that I can read up on how to turn my Rails 3 application into a server with a remote API?

Thankful for all input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

a good starting point might be reading up on [REST and responders](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/)

Then to interact with the API from another rails app, you can use ActiveResource. There's a [Railscast on it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics).

An example:

```
#API side
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    @products = Product.all
    respond_with(@products)
  end
end

#Client
# models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://your-api-app.com"
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Despite of what had been already told, you can start with [rails api screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem). Although it's meant for an API only application.

If you want to add and API to an existent full rails app, check [this blog post](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/04/08/api-with-ruby-on-rails-useful-tricks/) which covers the essentials on a Rails API, including tips for speed-up.

Since this should be a requirement too, for securing your API there's also a screencast on the subject: [#352 Securing an API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api)

Yehuda Katz and Ryan Bigg's book, [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz/), has a chapter on building a test-driven JSON API on top of the example application that runs through the entire book.

The code for the sample application in the book, [Ticketee](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee), is open source and can be found on GitHub. In particular, everything API-related is namespaced under /app/controllers/api and you can find plenty of RSpec tests in /spec/api.

Answer (score 4):

The [rails-api](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api) gem is a Rails subset that only includes the minimum modules needed to create an API app. It's intended to be lightweight and faster than a normal Rails application.

Check http://railscasts.com/episodes/348-the-rails-api-gem for a nice tutorial on how to use the gem.

Answer (score 4):

Came up with a [blog post](http://railsware.com/blog/2013/04/08/api-with-ruby-on-rails-useful-tricks/) recently - describes in examples how to add API to an existing Ruby on Rails application. Covers topics like Rails Metal controllers, routing, views and security.
Hope that will help.